# AngularJS: Error Duplicates on ngOptions

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

How can I prevent error logs of duplicates when displaying this?

```
<select class="ea-input" ng-model="details.amount" ng-options="amount as amount for amount in amounts">
  <option value="" disabled>{{'prepaid.selectamount.placeholder'|translate}}</option>
</select>
```

This works but I keep getting a console error of duplicates:

> angular.js:11496 Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] Duplicates in a repeater are
>   not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys.
>   Repeater: amount in eaOptions, Duplicate key: number:9999, Duplicate
>   value: 9999

I tried all the possible solutions (from here) for ngOptions but that did not work for me. How else should I take on this approach?

[EDIT]: The values of $scope.amounts are like this:
[5, 10, 15, 30, 50, 100]

[UPDATE]: There seems to be no problem with anything. I figured that it was a non-related directive that was causing this. Somewhere on the template another directive is calling the same `ng-model` and that is the one causing it.

```
<span ng-if="paymentDetails.maximizer.length > 0">   
                <cashier-maximizer-field ea-options="paymentDetails.maximizer" ea-model="details.amount">
                </cashier-maximizer-field>
                <div class="divider sm"></div>
            </span>
```

Comment: use track by $index in ng-options

Comment: @TarekSalahuddinMahmud `$index` is not available in ng-options.

Comment: What is the values inside amounts variable ? Can you create sample fiddle ?

Comment: There seems to be no problem with anything. I figured that it was a non-related directive that was causing this. Somewhere on the template another directive is calling the same ng-model and that is the one causing it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the option track by so internally angular will create its own ID and you avoid problems with dupe id in objects.

change your code with the following

```
ng-options="amount as amount for amount in amounts track by amount.id"
```

EDIT: Sorry I get confused with ng-repeat directive. You can use track by with a little change. I'm supposing that you have inside your amount object and id. You can change the "id" for another property if necessary. Here you have more info

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

Comment: This does not work. And I read somewhere that this only applies for `ng-repeat`.

Comment: `$index` is not available in ng-options. You can, however, use a `track by` expression and assign it to a value unique to each option.

Comment: You can do `track by $id(amount)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
{{'prepaid.selectamount.placeholder'|translate}}
```

is making the issue. Without it works fine.

Check the code below

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.details={};
  $scope.amounts =  [5, 10, 15, 30, 50, 100];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

  <select class="ea-input" ng-model="details.amount" ng-options=" amount for amount in amounts ">
    <option value="" disabled>Select</option>
  </select>
  {{selectedName}}
</div>
```

Comment: Nope. Removed that as well. Error is still there.

Answer (score 0):

try this 
    ng-options="amount for amount in amounts"